# (2x) zsh: command not found

Tags: zsh

I've finally decided to take the plunge and try out zsh. Running on a CentOS 7 machine. The only thing I find strangely aggravating is that for some reason each time I enter an unknown command, I get command not found twice:

For example, if I type "fail"

```
zsh: fail: command not found...
zsh: command not found: fail
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is the case, or find anyone else that seems to have had this problem. Perhaps my Google-fu is not strong enough, but any pointers would be appreciated.

my .zsh is just the basic one so far:

```
HISTFILE=~/.histfile
HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=10000

bindkey -e


zstyle :compinstall filename '/home/bmgraves/.zshrc'
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

with bash:

```
bash: fail: command not found...
```

tcsh:

```
fail: Command not found.



print $+functions[command_not_found_handler]

+zsh:2> print 1
 1
```

zsh -x:

```
+zsh:7> fail
+command_not_found_handle:1> local 'runcnf=1'
+command_not_found_handle:2> local 'retval=127'
+command_not_found_handle:5> [[ $- -regex-match i ]]
+command_not_found_handle:8> [ '!' -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket ']'
+command_not_found_handle:11> [ '!' -x /usr/libexec/packagekitd ']'
+command_not_found_handle:14> [ ']'
+command_not_found_handle:17> [ 1 -eq 1 ']'
+command_not_found_handle:18> /usr/libexec/pk-command-not-found fail
zsh: fail: command not found...
+command_not_found_handle:19> retval=127
+command_not_found_handle:26> return 127
zsh: command not found: fail
```

Comment: This does not happen with another shell, then?

Comment: Correct, Added bash/tcsh output  as an example. With that by side by side, it almost looks like zsh is printing the bash command not found as well as one for zsh, but i have no idea what would cause that :\

Comment: `zsh -x` might be handy to see what is going on. Or, what does `print $+functions[command_not_found_handler]` show?

Comment: added outputs above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a command is not found, [zsh invokes the function `command_not_found_handler`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html#index-command_005fnot_005ffound_005fhandler). A typical use for this function is to suggest a way to install the command, if it's part of a package that's part of your distribution but isn't installed.

In zsh, if the function returns a nonzero status, zsh prints its usual error message. Bash has a similar feature (there the function is called `command_not_found_handle`), but with a slight difference: in bash, if the command returns a nonzero status, bash doesn't print an error message.

From the trace, you seem to be using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/command-not-found/command-not-found.plugin.zsh). It's calling `pk-command-not-found`, which is Fedora's command-not-found handler, and which prints its own error message because it was designed for bash. I don't see an obvious way to suppress one of the error messages. If this really bothers you, you can remove the `command-not-found` plugin from your oh-my-zsh configuration (in which case you won't get prompted to install the package containing a command if it's available in the repositories but not installed).

Comment: Hmm, Unfortunately not actually using oh-my-zsh, so i'm not sure how i'll end up dealing with it, but what your saying at least gives me an answer. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Gravy If this doesn't come from your `.zshrc` then presumably your distribution or your system administrator has put something similar in `/etc/zshrc`.